# Should use Linq or Not?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, architecture, linq-to-entities

I am designing my project architecture.
In our team debate in on whether to use Linq or Not.

I surf on Google about the linq I found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/linqtosql/thread/cd952b8e-4bc6-4be9-87d3-cec7fbe7a0d8) which has given the brief advantages and disadvantages of linq.

There are 3 critical point from our project point of view.

1. DBML concurrency issues
2. small data sets will take longer to build the query than execute
3. joins are very slow

Am talking about Linq to Entities. All these are Linq related issues which are critical one according to my project requirement as my project is quite big.
So performance is very important key factor.

Can we solve these linq Issues? If yes, How to solve it?

Comment: Too vague.  Ask a single, concrete technical question.

Comment: @OliverBock what is vague in it?? what u don't understand?

Comment: Are you planning to use linq-to-xml ? linq-to-sql ? linq-to-objects? There are a lot of factors to consider before you can make an informed decision. Linq in itself can be used to do a huge variety of operations. One cannot give a general recommendation for a project based on theory.

Comment: @ryadavilli Am planing for Linq-to-sql

Comment: If performance would actulaly be important factor you'd try several approaches and find answer yourself if using LINQ is useful. As it stands currently the question can't be answered - one can solve any issues, but noone will be able to tell if some particular technology is good for *your* project.

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to LINQ to SQL? It has a simple-minded one-to-one mapping between database tables and the objects you program against. Not very capable compared to LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read through some of the responses in that post and i have to agree and disagree with a lot of them. I find the most important factor in using linq the quick turn around in development time. No more typos in SQL queries. Not wasting time in creating complex SQL queries. Also there's a difference in linq to entities and linq to sql. You didn't consider that. I suggest you read up on it. Hint: go for linq to entities.

Answers to your questions.

1. I don't relate concurrency issues to linq (to entities). It's how you implement it. If you need raw speed for (batch)updates you can always use ADO.NET.
2. If you contstruct your linq queries carefully, you pull only the data you need. If you're worried about linq taking a performance hit in constructing queries you can create compiled linq queries.
3. If you create a proper model with all the relationships in place joins won't be slow.

Answer (score 1):

As always, the answer to this is that it depends. The direction these days is definitely [pro-ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software). While you definitely have a lot more control over performance and atomic record updating with stored procedures or straight sql commands, in my personal experience those benefits are outweighed by the amount of time you'll spend maintaining/updating schemas and procedures. It can be a big slow down for an Agile team. Another key benefit of using strongly-typed ORM tools like Entity Framework or N-Hibernate is that you can prevent your code from diverging heavily from your database schema and stored procedures. This can cause some very large problems.

In general, I would error on using an ORM tool and then using stored procedures when necessary.

To answer your specific questions, using Entity Framework as the specific example:

1. Entity Framework 4 has some tools to help deal with [OptimisticConcurrencyExceptions](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application). You can attempt resolve it yourself or throw the exception up the stack.
2. This is probably a micro-optimization. In general, Entity Framework is very fast. You're more likely to deal with I/O issues before you hit a roadblock with this.
3. Joins can be slow if you're doing lots of round-tripping with the database or lazy loading. Entity Framework also supports [eager-loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx) so that everything can be done in a single query.

Ultimately, if comes down to it you can always use stored procedures when you need to. I do this when I have a lot of concurrent operations that need exclusive row locks.

One downside I have seen with EntityFramework is that has issues working with Postgres sometimes, but there are non-Visual Studio tools to help.